# Print out the letter from output from input

Tags: python, python-3.x

I made this function and I want to adapt it to take two parameters. One for the letter and one for the number. The function should print the appropriate amount of letters. (e.g. If the user types "monkey" and "3" the function will output "mon")

So far this is my code

```
word = input ("What is your word?")
number = input ("What is your number? ")
def test():

    letter=word[0]
    print (letter)

test()
```

Answer (score 2):

Is that what you want?

```
word = input("What is your word?")
number = int(input("What is your number? "))

def test(word, number):
    print(word[:number])

test(word, number)
```

Result:

```
What is your word?monkey    
What is your number? 3    
mon
```

Comment: I'm using Python2, try `word[:int(number)]`

Comment: it comes up with invalid syntax

Comment: Well in any case, please don't down vote a solution just because it is using a different Python version to yours.

Comment: i never did ;P i need at least 15 reputation

Comment: Ok sorry for the blind accusation!

Comment: @Jakus: No, that's impossible. What's the error are you getting?

Comment: If Jakus is using Python 3 then raw_input can't be used. Only use input. You also don't need to add quotes around the word being provided. Will also have to convert number to int.

Answer (score 0):

```
word = input ("What is your word: ")
number = input ("What is your number: ")

def test():
    print(word[:int(number)])

test()
```

This should not give you your syntax error that you mentioned in **Julien Bernu's** question.

*Note: This is assuming you are using the latest version of python*